# Is the sentence "I could see his pulse beating." correct?

Tags: vocabulary, collocation

Can we use the verb "beat" for "pulse"? If not, what *can* we use?
Thank you

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine and idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks a million

Comment: It's not incorrect, but it's not all that common. 8000 hits on Google for "see his pulse beating". It involves a transferred usage; 'pulse' fundamentally means the throb, arguably abstract. But one certainly speaks of feeling a pulse. Less idiomatic is 'feeling a pulse beating'. However, as 'seeing a pulse' perhaps sounds a little odd, padding (beating, beating steadily, pounding, fluttering ...), often an ameliorator,  is advisable.

Comment: Much appreciated.
And by the way, may I ask which website you use to see how many times something has been used on google?

Comment: @levi Look at [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams). Although, to be honest, I can't tell how to get an actual count from that. I wouldn't use Google directly, because you often get multiple entries that point to the same thing.

Comment: @Edwin, Unusually, I think you're going too far… or not far enough.

How could "see" a/his pulse be different from "feel" a/his pulse?

Without research, I suggest "… see his pulse beating…” is at worst clearly idiomatic, even if there are rules it breaks.

Can this really about anything but the difference between a strict "… see his pulse…” and a common-or garden "… see his pulse beating…”?

Comment: @Robbie All there except the third sentence is purely idiomaticity- (ie frequency of use) referencing. As regards logicality, one can certainly on rarish occasions see the effects of a pulse (the rippling), and almost invariably feel the effects of a pulse (the pulsating). The tricky bit is where metonym is deemed proper (see the pulse; feel the pulse). 'Feel' the pulse is less of a metonymic distancing. // Compare 'boiled a kettle' (pretty idiomatic) v 'boiled a pan' (not followed by of/filled/full/containing ...) (used, but not too common) v 'boiled an urn / a bowl' (unidiomatic).

Comment: ... 'The pen is mightier than the sword'. But _not_ 'The pencil / artist's brush / microphone / camera / ...'. ///  'The fish dish was mouth-watering' _Not_ 'plate'.